# How to change the default compiler of Linux Mint 18.0 from version 5.3.1 to a version below 4.0?

Tags: linux, g++

I need to compile a special program (i.e. configuring, making, and making install processes of nest) by an old version of g++ such as 3.3 or 3.4. However, I don't have such versions in my package manager.

I downloaded g++-3.0-3.0.4-7_alpha-deb, but I don't know if it is the true version for Linux, or how can I install it and set as the default compiler. I will appreciate if any one informs me of its possible dangers to my Linux (as I read in Google).

Comment: Please have a look at [ask]

Comment: The OP made an answer with an error he/she is experiencing, but this was deleted since it is not an answer. It is generally expected this should be copied into the question, and since that has not happened, I am taking the view that the question is incomplete and abandoned. For now, voting to place on hold.

Answer (score 0):

First : You can have as many versions of gcc, g++ as you want, installed at the same time.

The default Mint 18, Ubuntu 16.04 versions are :

```
sudo apt install g++ g++-4.7 g++-4.8 g++-4.9
```

The reliable gcc, g++ version 3.4.6 : `compat-gcc34-3.4.6-ubuntu1204-1_amd64.deb` 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7S255p3kFXNRTkzQnRSNXZ6UVU/view?usp=sharing
 , and `compat-gcc-34-c++_3.4.6-20_amd64.deb` https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7S255p3kFXNV3J3bnVoWGNWdG8/view?usp=sharing

Please install with `sudo dpkg -i compat-gcc*`

Using, examples : 1) `export CC=gcc34 CXX=g++34 && [other command]` , like  2) `export CC=gcc34 CXX=g++34 && ./configure` ... and 3) `make CC=gcc34 CXX=g++34`

Comment: Thanks Knud. But again I ran into problem:... ~/Downloads $ export CC=gcc34 CXX=g++34 && ./configure
bash: ./configure: No such file or directory
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: » need to compile a special program (i.e. configuring ...) « : Well, if it isn't `./configure` , I guess you know where and which command to use for your unknown program.